# mouseenter not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to display a class using mousenter like so:

```
$(".stcommenttext").live({
    mouseenter:
        function() {
            $(this).attr('class');
        },
    mouseleave:
       function() {
       }
   }
);
```

my HTML and CSS look like this:

```
 <div class="stcommentbody" id='stcommentbody19'>

        <div class="stcommentimg">
            <a href="/view_profile.php?id=5" style="border:0;"><img src="/photos/files/5/main/small_thumb.jpg?v=1348065832" class='small_face'/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="stcommenttext">
            <input type="hidden" id="home19" value="1" />
            <a class="stcommentdelete" href="#" id="cmt_19" rel="tooltip" title="Delete Comment"></a>                    
            <a href="/view_profile.php?id=5" style="border:0;"><b>psmith</b></a>  hello             <div class="stcommenttime">8 minutes ago <span style="float:right;"><img id="delcmticon_69" class="saving" src="/images/busy.gif" /></span></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stcommentbody" id='stcommentbody20'>

        <div class="stcommentimg">
            <a href="/view_profile.php?id=5" style="border:0;"><img src="/photos/files/5/main/small_thumb.jpg?v=1348065832" class='small_face'/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="stcommenttext">
            <input type="hidden" id="home20" value="1" />
            <a class="stcommentdelete" href="#" id="cmt_20" rel="tooltip" title="Delete Comment"></a>                    
            <a href="/view_profile.php?id=5" style="border:0;"><b>psmith</b></a>  testing this              <div class="stcommenttime">7 minutes ago <span style="float:right;"><img id="delcmticon_69" class="saving" src="/images/busy.gif" /></span></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stcommentdelete {
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:url(/wall/icons/trashdull.png);
    display: none;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
.stbody:hover .stcommentdelete {
    display: block;
}
.stcommentdelete:hover {
    background:url(/wall/icons/trash.png);
}
```

I would expect it to show my delete icon upon mouseenter for the individual div but it's showing the icon for all divs.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using.  If 1.7+ you should be using `on` in place of `live`.  And is this the actual code?  Because `$(this).attr('class');` does nothing.

Comment: You said you "want to display a class". Display a class where? This line of code `$(this).attr('class');` will not do anything ...

Comment: I would assume that's my issue then.  I'm trying to toggle the display attribute for the .stcommentdelete class

Comment: display attribute? Do you mean the display CSS property? So you want to toggle the .stcommentdelete when clicking on the outer .stcommenttext?

Comment: No I want to show the delete icon when I mosuseover the stcommentbody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".stcommenttext").on({
    mouseenter:
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('stcommentdelete');
        },
    mouseleave:
       function() {
            $(this).removeClass('stcommentdelete');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to show the .stcommentdelete element when you hover the .stcommentbody elements?

```
$('.stcommentbody').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.stcommentdelete').show();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.stcommentdelete').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. see [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
you can use `.on()` instead of `.live()` or use `.mouseover` and `.mouseleave` separately like this.

```
$(".stcommenttext").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).addClass('class');
}).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('class');
});
```

see [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hover` with multiple functions for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, like this:

```
$(".stcommentbody").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".stcommentdelete").addClass('stcommentdelete-active');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".stcommentdelete").removeClass('stcommentdelete-active');
    }
);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/Vg2vZ/ (I used your exact markup with different images)